# Accessing WebSphere MQ message properties in Biztalk orchestration

Tags: biztalk, ibm-mq

I need to read Websphere queue name from my orchestration. The queue is configured with MQSC transport.

Can anyone supply a code example for accessing some MQ properties of incoming message? Do I need to reference a special DLL for this or is it available out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed the adapter all then you will be able to access the
[MQSeries Context Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559055.aspx) and don't need to specifically reference the DLL.

For the queue name you will probably want the MQXQH_RemoteQName context property.

To use the property in an BizTalk shape (expression, decision) you would have something like

```
Message_Name(MQSeries.MQXQH_RemoteQName)
```

Where Message_Name is the name of your message in the Orchestration.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this.